# How can I switch from one UITabbarview controller to another UITabbarViewController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I have an UITabbarViewController with 3 tabbar items with a navigationbar. When I will press my first item of tabbar item there will be a button at the view.

Now my question is when I will press the button, then it will go to the another tabbarview controller which have also 3 tabbar items. How can I do that?

UITabbarViewController[with navigation bar]--->tabaritem [1] + tabaritem [2] + tabaritem [3]

tabaritem [1] viewcontroller is taking a button when I will press button the another UITabbarcontroller will be shown at the screen.

UITabbarcontroller[2] [with navigation bar]--->tabaritem [1] + tabaritem [2] + tabaritem [3]

I am new to iPhone application development.

One more thing is that I can't use table view for two tabbarcontroller because my first tabbar item of first tabbar is taking a login page so when user will able to log in then he will see second tabbarviewcontroller.

Comment: @Akshay: i have already make my first tabbarviewcontroller and first tabbar item taking the login page with a login button. Now when i will press that button then it will go to another tabbar controller which is containing 3 different tabbar items. if u can please give me the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of swapping out the whole controller, why not just remove and add tab bar items for each of your modes?  When your in your first mode, show tab bar items 1,2 and 3.  If someone hits one, then remove all those items, and add items 4,5 and 6.  Use the tag on the items to keep track of them.

Comment: Thank you very very much Owen Hartnett.it works very nicely.thank you again

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this, according to apples viewpoints, is to show one of the tab bars in a modal.

It seems like you're using the first Tabbarcontroller as a Login controller. In that case, you would have this as a Modalview over you're other (normal) Viewcontroller. On Application Start, you load the main tab controller.
You then check if the user is logged in and show the Model Logging Controller (which is a Tabbar controller again) if he isn't.
Once the user has successfully logged in, you just dismiss the Modal, and voila, you got the "main" tab controller visible.

[edit:] here's a short example in (Pseuod) code:
MainViewController.m:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)anmiated 
 {  
   UIApplicationDelegate* appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   if (!appDelegate.isLoggedIn) {
      appDelegate.loginController = [[UIViewController alloc ] initFromNib:@"login"];
      [self presentModalViewController:appDelegate.loginController animated:NO];
   }

 }
```

in the LoginController

```
- (iBAction) loginClicked
  {
    [appDelegate.mainViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  }
```

This obviously assumes that you have references to your view controllers in the appdelegate.

Comment: thanks at first for your answer.i have understand what do u want to say but if you give me an example then it will very much helpful.because i did not do such kind of things before. so if you give me your technique using an example it will so glad to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help.now let me try this.:)